# Extract some strings

Tags: regex

need some help with this RegEx magic..

I have this:
`<a href="/en/node/1032/delete?destination=node%2F5%2Fblog">delete</a>`

and this:

```
(<a)*([^>]*>)[^<]*(</a>)



$1 = <a
$2 = href="/en/node/1032/delete?destination=node%2F5%2Fblog">
$3 = </a>
```

I need some aditional strings:

- `1032`
- `href="/en/`  en is dynamic!

How can I get this strings?

Used in php

Answer (score 1):

Your sample could be captured with

`(<a)\b.*?((href="/en/).*?(?</)(\d+)/.*?").*?>).*?(</a>)`

...but perhaps replacing the "en" with something broader, depending on what you want to capture.

HOWEVER, and I want to emphasize this, **[don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**. The above regex won't work for certain HTML-valid input, and due to the [limitations of regex](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx) it cannot be refined to work for every possible case. You'll get better, more correct results with an HTML or XML parser.

Comment: this is not working ..  what do you think is better to use some php string functions?

Comment: @user633163 I haven't used PHP in some time, but I think you want the `DOMDocument` class: http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html and http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php Use `getElementsByTagName('a')` and grab the `href` attribute. Split the resulting string on the `/` character and you should have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

([^/ ]). That will give you
href="
en
node
1032

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but you can use the regex to get the groups and get your data.